# Access Resultset without transforming it to Json or XML ballerina.io

Tags: ballerina

I am trying to access the plain resultset without transforming it to json or XML.

My database transforms the resultset into the correct format.

Example:

```
var resultSet = testDB->select("SELECT * FROM test , ());
           
            if (resultSet is table<record {}>)
            { 

            }
```

When I try to run foreach over resultSet I get an empty field.

versions: ballerina --version
jBallerina 1.2.8
Language specification 2020R1
Update Tool 0.8.8

Many greetings, Martin

Answer (score 2):

The result is a stream of records where you can access each record and their fields.

You can create a result stream and iterate over it as following sample code while accessing each field

```
stream<record{}, error> resultStream =
    mysqlClient->query("Select * from Customers");

error? e = resultStream.forEach(function(record {} result) {
    io:println("Customer full details: ", result);
    io:println("Customer first name: ", result["FirstName"]);
    io:println("Customer last name: ", result["LastName"]);
});
```

You can refer more [JDBC examples](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/jdbc-query-operation.html) in [Ballerina By Examples](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/)